# unterminated string constant error only with IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Ok i got this error in IE 8 and 9, this is Ajax call

```
$('#$id').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
$("#{$this->name}_div").hide();
$("#{$this->name}_message").hide(); 
$("#{$this->name}_message").show().html('<img src="$gif">');
},
success: function(response)
{
     var response = JSON.parse(response);
     if (response.error != 'undefined')
{
...
}

}
```

Problem is in this line of JavaScript code

```
 var response = JSON.parse(response);
```

My Javescript, broke, script works in othere browsers and in Internet explorer 10, i am worried if someone with older IE try to visit my site. Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: So you think is error in response

Comment: Is `response` a valid JSON string?

Comment: yes works in other browsers and ie 10

Comment: @VladimirŠtus Given that the error is happening on that line, there's a pretty good chance that it has something to do with the value of `response`.

Comment: Can you log the response and post it here?

Comment: just a sec need to restart pc my IE crash cannot enter developer tools

Comment: ie 9 have so many issues, its its impossible to solve them all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to parse the JSON yourself? `ajaxForm` provides a `dataType` option for that:

```
$('#$id').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#{$this->name}_div").hide();
        $("#{$this->name}_message").hide(); 
        $("#{$this->name}_message").show().html('<img src="$gif">');
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
       if (response.error != 'undefined') {
           ...
       }
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if there's something invalid in your JSON that other browsers just happen to be tolerating, then pretty much the only answer is to fix your JSON.